# Pass req res objects into socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sockets

I am a little confused how I can interact with the socket when I need to pass in data from my routes file. I have the standard setup using node.js, express, mongodb etc.

I'll run my socket.io logic inside server.js, and I include the routes.js inside that file.

`var routes = require('./app/routes');`

In this case I need to run some io.sockets inside my routes.js file.

My question is what is a good way to do this? I could run that specific route inside server.js but that gets messy. If I were to use sockets in my routes.js do I need to re-require

`var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);`

That means I need to create a new http server object, and I don't like that since I am requiring this file in server.js, this seems like a counter-intuitive move to me.

So how do I make a request to the server and pass for example a user name?

**Example:**

```
app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {

    res.render('profile', { user : req.user });

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log(socket);
            console.log(req.user); // Here I have access to the user and can pass that around in                        my sockets
    });

});
```

I am also using route middleware, so I'd like to keep that in my routes.js, IDK I am just confused what I should do, hopefully someone understands my angle here?

**Edit:**

What about passing something into the routes?

```
routes.initialize(app, passport);
```

Comment: socket.io and express are 2 different frameworks working with completely different protocols, what you are trying to do cannot work.Express should deliver the initial (html) PAYLOAD then let socket.io do it's work,when the client attempts a connection to socket.io (with javascript). But dont try to mashup both. It cannot work.

Comment: yeah but they should still be able to pass data.. I passed the `io` object into the routes. `routes.initialize(app, passport, io);` I have access to the object now and can create a new socket connection now inside my routes.js

Comment: The best way to create a live chat with users would be to add the users that are logged in to the database to the socket, just creating an object with the response. When a user logs out I will drop the username from the object.

Comment: Please correct me if I sound silly lol. To me this makes sense to me I don't want to sound naive here but, passing the io object to my routes works well so far. Any objections or forever hold your peace.

Comment: I know it's been quite a long time since you posted the question but did you ever find an answer to your issue? I am having the same issue!

Answer (score -1):

You can get the `req` and `res` objects directly in the socket by invoking `socket.request` (a `Getter` function which is available via `__proto__`). [See docs](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket#request:request).

I was then able to find `req.user` in `socket.request.client.user`.